# Normalizing images passed to torch.transforms.Compose function

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, normalize

How to find the values to pass to the transforms.Normalize function in PyTorch? Also, where in my code, should I exactly do the transforms.Normalize?

Since normalizing the dataset is a pretty well-known task, I was hoping there should be some sort of script for doing that automatically. At least I couldn't find it in PyTorch forum.

```py
transformed_dataset = MothLandmarksDataset(csv_file='moth_gt.csv',
                                           root_dir='.',
                                           transform=transforms.Compose([
                                           Rescale(256),
                                           RandomCrop(224),
                                           transforms.Normalize(mean = [ 0.485, 0.456, 0.406 ],
                                           std = [ 0.229, 0.224, 0.225 ]),
                                           ToTensor()
                                               ]))
    
for i in range(len(transformed_dataset)):
    sample = transformed_dataset[i]
    print(i, sample['image'].size(), sample['landmarks'].size())
    if i == 3:
       break
```

I know these current values don't pertain to my dataset and pertain to ImageNet but using them I actually get an error:

```py
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-81-eb8dc46e0284> in <module>
         10 
         11 for i in range(len(transformed_dataset)):
    ---> 12     sample = transformed_dataset[i]
         13 
         14     print(i, sample['image'].size(), sample['landmarks'].size())
    
    <ipython-input-48-9d04158922fb> in __getitem__(self, idx)
         30 
         31         if self.transform:
    ---> 32             sample = self.transform(sample)
         33 
         34         return sample
    
    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py in __call__(self, img)
         59     def __call__(self, img):
         60         for t in self.transforms:
    ---> 61             img = t(img)
         62         return img
         63 
    
    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py in __call__(self, tensor)
        210             Tensor: Normalized Tensor image.
        211         """
    --> 212         return F.normalize(tensor, self.mean, self.std, self.inplace)
        213 
        214     def __repr__(self):
    
    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py in normalize(tensor, mean, std, inplace)
        278     """
        279     if not torch.is_tensor(tensor):
    --> 280         raise TypeError('tensor should be a torch tensor. Got {}.'.format(type(tensor)))
        281 
        282     if tensor.ndimension() != 3:
    
    TypeError: tensor should be a torch tensor. Got <class 'dict'>.
```

So basically three questions:

1. How can I find the similar values as in ImageNet mean and std for my own custom dataset?
2. How to pass these values and where? I assume I should do it in transforms.Compose method but I might be wrong.
3. I assume I should apply Normalize to my entire dataset not just the training set, am I right?

### Update:

Trying the provided solution here didn't work for me: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/about-normalization-using-pre-trained-vgg16-networks/23560/6?u=mona_jalal

```py
mean = 0.
std = 0.
nb_samples = 0.
for data in dataloader:
    print(type(data))
    batch_samples = data.size(0)
    
    data.shape(0)
    data = data.view(batch_samples, data.size(1), -1)
    mean += data.mean(2).sum(0)
    std += data.std(2).sum(0)
    nb_samples += batch_samples

mean /= nb_samples
std /= nb_samples
```

error is:

```py
<class 'dict'>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-e8ba3c8718bb> in <module>
      5 for data in dataloader:
      6     print(type(data))
----> 7     batch_samples = data.size(0)
      8 
      9     data.shape(0)

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'size'
```

this is print(data) result:

```py
{'image': tensor([[[[0.2961, 0.2941, 0.2941,  ..., 0.2460, 0.2456, 0.2431],
          [0.2953, 0.2977, 0.2980,  ..., 0.2442, 0.2431, 0.2431],
          [0.2941, 0.2941, 0.2980,  ..., 0.2471, 0.2471, 0.2448],
          ...,
          [0.3216, 0.3216, 0.3216,  ..., 0.2482, 0.2471, 0.2471],
          [0.3216, 0.3241, 0.3253,  ..., 0.2471, 0.2471, 0.2450],
          [0.3216, 0.3216, 0.3216,  ..., 0.2471, 0.2452, 0.2431]],

         [[0.2961, 0.2941, 0.2941,  ..., 0.2460, 0.2456, 0.2431],
          [0.2953, 0.2977, 0.2980,  ..., 0.2442, 0.2431, 0.2431],
          [0.2941, 0.2941, 0.2980,  ..., 0.2471, 0.2471, 0.2448],
          ...,
          [0.3216, 0.3216, 0.3216,  ..., 0.2482, 0.2471, 0.2471],
          [0.3216, 0.3241, 0.3253,  ..., 0.2471, 0.2471, 0.2450],
          [0.3216, 0.3216, 0.3216,  ..., 0.2471, 0.2452, 0.2431]],

         [[0.2961, 0.2941, 0.2941,  ..., 0.2460, 0.2456, 0.2431],
          [0.2953, 0.2977, 0.2980,  ..., 0.2442, 0.2431, 0.2431],
          [0.2941, 0.2941, 0.2980,  ..., 0.2471, 0.2471, 0.2448],
          ...,
          [0.3216, 0.3216, 0.3216,  ..., 0.2482, 0.2471, 0.2471],
          [0.3216, 0.3241, 0.3253,  ..., 0.2471, 0.2471, 0.2450],
          [0.3216, 0.3216, 0.3216,  ..., 0.2471, 0.2452, 0.2431]]],


        [[[0.3059, 0.3093, 0.3140,  ..., 0.3373, 0.3363, 0.3345],
          [0.3059, 0.3093, 0.3165,  ..., 0.3412, 0.3389, 0.3373],
          [0.3098, 0.3131, 0.3176,  ..., 0.3450, 0.3412, 0.3412],
          ...,
          [0.2931, 0.2966, 0.2931,  ..., 0.2549, 0.2539, 0.2510],
          [0.2902, 0.2902, 0.2902,  ..., 0.2510, 0.2510, 0.2502],
          [0.2864, 0.2900, 0.2863,  ..., 0.2510, 0.2510, 0.2510]],

         [[0.3059, 0.3093, 0.3140,  ..., 0.3373, 0.3363, 0.3345],
          [0.3059, 0.3093, 0.3165,  ..., 0.3412, 0.3389, 0.3373],
          [0.3098, 0.3131, 0.3176,  ..., 0.3450, 0.3412, 0.3412],
          ...,
          [0.2931, 0.2966, 0.2931,  ..., 0.2549, 0.2539, 0.2510],
          [0.2902, 0.2902, 0.2902,  ..., 0.2510, 0.2510, 0.2502],
          [0.2864, 0.2900, 0.2863,  ..., 0.2510, 0.2510, 0.2510]],

         [[0.3059, 0.3093, 0.3140,  ..., 0.3373, 0.3363, 0.3345],
          [0.3059, 0.3093, 0.3165,  ..., 0.3412, 0.3389, 0.3373],
          [0.3098, 0.3131, 0.3176,  ..., 0.3450, 0.3412, 0.3412],
          ...,
          [0.2931, 0.2966, 0.2931,  ..., 0.2549, 0.2539, 0.2510],
          [0.2902, 0.2902, 0.2902,  ..., 0.2510, 0.2510, 0.2502],
          [0.2864, 0.2900, 0.2863,  ..., 0.2510, 0.2510, 0.2510]]],


        [[[0.2979, 0.2980, 0.3015,  ..., 0.2825, 0.2784, 0.2784],
          [0.2980, 0.2980, 0.2980,  ..., 0.2830, 0.2764, 0.2795],
          [0.2980, 0.2980, 0.3012,  ..., 0.2827, 0.2814, 0.2797],
          ...,
          [0.3282, 0.3293, 0.3294,  ..., 0.2238, 0.2235, 0.2235],
          [0.3255, 0.3255, 0.3255,  ..., 0.2240, 0.2235, 0.2229],
          [0.3225, 0.3255, 0.3255,  ..., 0.2216, 0.2235, 0.2223]],

         [[0.2979, 0.2980, 0.3015,  ..., 0.2825, 0.2784, 0.2784],
          [0.2980, 0.2980, 0.2980,  ..., 0.2830, 0.2764, 0.2795],
          [0.2980, 0.2980, 0.3012,  ..., 0.2827, 0.2814, 0.2797],
          ...,
          [0.3282, 0.3293, 0.3294,  ..., 0.2238, 0.2235, 0.2235],
          [0.3255, 0.3255, 0.3255,  ..., 0.2240, 0.2235, 0.2229],
          [0.3225, 0.3255, 0.3255,  ..., 0.2216, 0.2235, 0.2223]],

         [[0.2979, 0.2980, 0.3015,  ..., 0.2825, 0.2784, 0.2784],
          [0.2980, 0.2980, 0.2980,  ..., 0.2830, 0.2764, 0.2795],
          [0.2980, 0.2980, 0.3012,  ..., 0.2827, 0.2814, 0.2797],
          ...,
          [0.3282, 0.3293, 0.3294,  ..., 0.2238, 0.2235, 0.2235],
          [0.3255, 0.3255, 0.3255,  ..., 0.2240, 0.2235, 0.2229],
          [0.3225, 0.3255, 0.3255,  ..., 0.2216, 0.2235, 0.2223]]]],
       dtype=torch.float64), 'landmarks': tensor([[[160.2964,  98.7339],
         [223.0788,  72.5067],
         [ 82.4163,  70.3733],
         [152.3213, 137.7867]],

        [[198.3194,  74.4341],
         [273.7188, 118.7733],
         [117.7113,  80.8000],
         [182.0750, 107.2533]],

        [[137.4789,  92.8523],
         [174.9463,  40.3467],
         [ 57.3013,  59.1200],
         [129.3375, 131.6533]]], dtype=torch.float64)}
```

```py
dataloader = DataLoader(transformed_dataset, batch_size=3,
                        shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
```

and

```py
transformed_dataset = MothLandmarksDataset(csv_file='moth_gt.csv',
                                           root_dir='.',
                                           transform=transforms.Compose(
                                               [
                                               Rescale(256),
                                               RandomCrop(224),
                                               
                                               ToTensor()#,
                                               ##transforms.Normalize(mean = [ 0.485, 0.456, 0.406 ],
                                               ##         std = [ 0.229, 0.224, 0.225 ])
                                               ]
                                                                        )
                                           )
```

and

```py
class MothLandmarksDataset(Dataset):
    """Face Landmarks dataset."""

    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform=None):
        """
        Args:
            csv_file (string): Path to the csv file with annotations.
            root_dir (string): Directory with all the images.
            transform (callable, optional): Optional transform to be applied
                on a sample.
        """
        self.landmarks_frame = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.landmarks_frame)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if torch.is_tensor(idx):
            idx = idx.tolist()

        img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.landmarks_frame.iloc[idx, 0])
        image = io.imread(img_name)
        landmarks = self.landmarks_frame.iloc[idx, 1:]
        landmarks = np.array([landmarks])
        landmarks = landmarks.astype('float').reshape(-1, 2)
        sample = {'image': image, 'landmarks': landmarks}

        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)

        return sample
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Source code errors

> How to pass these values and where? I assume I should do it in
> transforms.Compose method but I might be wrong.

In `MothLandmarksDataset` it is no wonder it is not working as you are trying to pass `Dict` (`sample`) to `torchvision.transforms` which require either `torch.Tensor` or `PIL.Image` as input. here to be exact:

```
sample = {'image': image, 'landmarks': landmarks}

if self.transform:
    sample = self.transform(sample)
```

You **could** pass `sample["image"]` into it although **you shouldn't**. Applying this operation only to `sample["image"]` would break its relation to `landmarks`. What you should be after is something like `albumentations` library (see [here](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations)) which can transform `image` and `landmarks` in the same way to preserve their relations.

Also there is no `Rescale` transform in `torchvision`, maybe you meant [Resize](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Resize)?

### Mean and variance for normalization

Provided code is fine, **but you have to unpack your data into `torch.Tensor`** like this:

```
mean = 0.0
std = 0.0
nb_samples = 0.0
for data in dataloader:
    images, landmarks = data["image"], data["landmarks"]
    batch_samples = images.size(0)

    images_data = images.view(batch_samples, images.size(1), -1)
    mean += images_data.mean(2).sum(0)
    std += images_data.std(2).sum(0)
    nb_samples += batch_samples

mean /= nb_samples
std /= nb_samples
```

> How to pass these values and where? I assume I should do it in
> transforms.Compose method but I might be wrong.

Those values should be passed to `torchvision.transforms.Normalize` applied only to `sample["images"]`, not to `sample["landmarks"]`.

> I assume I should apply Normalize to my entire dataset not just the
> training set, am I right?

You should calculate normalization values across training dataset and apply those calculated values to validation and test as well.

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. When I ran your code snippet I got this error ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-bf2b6e51791b> in <module>
      6     batch_samples = images.size(0)
      7 
----> 8     images_data = images.view(batch_samples, data.size(1), -1)
      9     mean += images_data.mean(2).sum(0)
     10     std += images_data.std(2).sum(0)

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'size'

Comment: here's a screenshot of running the cell with your code snippet https://imgur.com/a/t34x3wa

Comment: Please see newest edit (changed this line to this: `images_data = images.view(batch_samples, images.size(1), -1)`)

Comment: Is it very wrong if I am finding the mean and std across the whole dataset not just the training set?

Comment: @MonaJalal yes, you are leaking information from test and validation set which may skew the results.

Comment: could you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64358283/runtimeerror-can-only-calculate-the-mean-of-floating-types-got-byte-instead-f  I ran it on train_loader but got error